# Is it possible to open a log file programmatically if it's continously being written to?

Tags: java, user-interface, file-io, log4j

Or will this generate an error? I just wanted to know if this were possible before I put forth the effort to implement this behavior into my application. Sorry for the naivety...

Note: I'm using log4j for logging, and by 'opening a log file programmatically', I mean through a GUI component, such as a button.

Comment: in the Un*x world it's quite common to watch growing log files using *tail -f logfile*...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never used log4j but used log4net a lot (its .NET counterpart).  You can set your log's lockingModel to Minimal-lock to have your log file locked only when the logger is actually writing to it.  At that point you can read from it without preventing your logger from writing if you make sure your application doesn't itself obtain an exclusive lock on the file.

Comment: How do I make sure the application doesn't itself obtain an exclusive lock? Should I use a wait-notify design using locks and conditions?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the exact way to do this in java, but you can most likely set your stream to allow sharing.  In .Net we use the FileShare.ReadWrite parameter when opening our stream.  You should try looking for something similar.

Answer (score 1):

It is platform dependent.  On Linux / UNIX it is likely to work, but I believe that Windows uses file locking by default and this may cause problems.

The best approach is to do some simple experiments on your implementation platform.